# How to return var in function WinJS

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2013, winjs

Im so tired with this, please help

```
function fileProperties(image){
    image.properties.getImagePropertiesAsync().then(function (chiTiet) {
        var imgWidth = chiTiet.width;
        var imgHeight = chiTiet.height;
        var imgBlob = URL.createObjectURL(image, { oneTimeOnly: true });
        var data = imgWidth + imgHeight + imgBlob;
        return data;
    });
}
```

This is not work. How i can return var data ?

Comment: Return an object with three properties.

Comment: Yes, return an object, each function has only one returned value.

Comment: Please clarify what you're asking http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
function fileProperties(image){
    return image.properties.getImagePropertiesAsync().then(function (chiTiet) {
        var imgWidth = chiTiet.width;
        var imgHeight = chiTiet.height;
        var imgBlob = URL.createObjectURL(image, { oneTimeOnly: true });
        var data = imgWidth + imgHeight + imgBlob;
        return {
            width: imgWidth,
            height: imgHeight,
            blob: imgBlob
        };
    });
}
```

To use it in your code:

```
fileProperties(myImage).then(function(properties) {
    console.log('Image width: ', properties.width);
    console.log('Image height: ', properties.height);
    console.log('Image blob: ', properties.blob);
});
```